# Change frames.render in an object of type Image

Tags: r, image-processing

I have an object of type Image which I want to recreate using the `EBImage::image()` command, which looks like this:

```
>im
Image 
colorMode    : Grayscale 
storage.mode : double 
dim          : 5 5 3 
frames.total : 3 
frames.render: 3 

imageData(object)[1:5,1:5,1]
         [,1]        [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  0.100877836 -0.06663118 -0.077078253 -0.083304137 -0.01695795
[2,]  0.014971112  0.04688030 -0.082847044 -0.043261390 -0.08951215
[3,]  0.090629555 -0.05716525 -0.013859576 -0.005152564 -0.06850447
[4,]  0.071357347 -0.06264605 -0.041013584 -0.057845186 -0.10428081
[5,] -0.002307055 -0.01245533 -0.003705411  0.049485780 -0.05529620
```

However, when I use the `image` command, I get the following warning:
`Missing frame index for an image stack, assuming 'i = 1'`
and get an image for each color channel.

How can I modify the `im` object to render it into a single image?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the color mode of your `im` object from `Grayscale` to `Color` by calling `colorMode(im) <- Color`. For details see the [Color Management](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html#4_color_management) section in the package vignette.